# Perl CPAN Module from command line?

Tags: perl, cpan

I found a Perl module that is often packaged on Debian. In my case I didn't have access to an updated package manager, but I do have Perl.

So I ran `cpan` which opened up cpan shell where I entered `install App::Ack`.

Now I want to run Ack from command line. Can anyone assist with the bash syntax for a relatively new Perl user?

The ubuntu version is used [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957175/773263): `ack 'text-to-find-here'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask Perl where it install its modules. When you run `perl -V` you get message like this:

```
  @INC:
   /usr/share/tlpkg/
   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/site_perl
   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/core_perl
```

Add those paths to `PATH` environment variable and run your program with `app/ack` or just `ack` depending on directory structure.